# Vim Taglist Plugin - Highlight For the Split

Tags: vim, plugins

In Vim TagList plugin , is it possible to change the highlight (color) of the Split bar that shows the + and | to expand or contract the listings ? I'd like it match the theme . I didnt see a mention in :help taglist for this .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That "split bar" is called "fold column". Its appearance is *not* dictated by TagList: it's your colorscheme's responsibility to define how it should look.

If you are not satisfied by its appearance, you can search for a line starting with `hi FoldColumn` in your colorscheme and edit it according to your taste.

Comment: Thanks romainl , I use Fold's but never understood where Fold Column applied .